# How to load a UIPickerView when the data source is asychronous (parse database)

Tags: asynchronous, parse-platform, swift3, uipickerview

I could not find this resolved anywhere on StackOverFlow.  Any help appreciated.

In summary, I start in viewDidLoad() by downloading a list of names from my parse.com (actually using back4app.com) into an array.  Of course, since the loading is done in the background, the main thread does not wait and keeps on trucking.

When my main thread hits the "numberOfRowsInComponent" delegate function to determine the number of rows that will be in my pickerview, it returns 0 because the array has yet to be loaded.

How do I get the numberOfRowsInComponent function below to understand that it needs to wait for the array to be loaded?

Thank you,

Phil

Comment: Why dont you hide your pickerview until the download completed? I think you dont want to show empty picker view.

Answer (score 1):

Once all element added in array then reload the component of picker and it again call the delegates and datasource of picker and you will see the all value will be reflected in pickerView.Also hide picker until downloaded complted and once it done then show the picker.